# Python: If the string has no substring of 7 of the same characters in a row, return True

Tags: python, python-3.x

I haven't encountered this problem before so I'm stuck. I just don't know what to write in my 'if' statement. What string method should I use in this case?

```
def func(string):
    if #I just don't know what to put in here:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
return not re.search('(.)\\1{6}', S)
```

Comment: Thanks for this! We haven't learned using 're' in class yet so is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Iterate over the string keeping the last seen character and incrementing the count each loop, clearing if a new character is seen.